# Pip installing latest version of matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

I wanted to use a functionality of matplotlib's more recent versions, and I noticed that my matplotlib is out of date. I tried upgrading it with pip, which was successful according to PIP. As can be seen in this screenshot:

[image]

As you can see pip says 1.4.6 is installed at `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`.

If I try the upgrade command, nothing new is installed as it says the most recent version is installed.
Nevertheless, If I import matplotlib and then check the version, you can see that 1.1.1 is installed. 
I also add the location of the site-packages folder.

Why, according to pip is the latested version installed, but when I import it, it is not the latest version ? Also in the site package folder I find: `matplotlib-1.4.2.dist-info`

I work on mac osx 10.9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your paths are messed up (most probably the `$PYTHONPATH`). Check the location of version 1.1.1 using

```
import matplotlib
print matplotlib.__file__
```

and you may see what's going on. I already saw multiple package installations in the same folder, so have a look at the files in site-packages too.
Of course you should delete the older package to avoid path confusion in future ; )

Comment: Ok, thx for pointing that out. I removed the matplotlib folder from the other location and then the correcti version was found in my /site-packages folder